# jQuery contains text and replace useage

Tags: jquery

I am using this function to replace a single item that contains "Home" in the menu , but I just looked on wireless view and when mobile is detected , the site creates a "Home" and a "Wireless Home" link , so my function is replacing both , and not just the "Home" button. How can i match "Home" exactly so "Wireless Home" is also not effected by this below ?

```
$("#hsubmenuitems a:contains('Home')").text('OVERVIEW').attr('href', 'http://%LIVESCORINGHOST%/%YEAR%/home/%LEAGUEID%?MODULE=MESSAGE12');
```

Comment: Create an id for each element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need a little more code:

```
$("#hsubmenuitems a").each(function() {
    var link = $(this),
        text = link.text();

    if (text == "Home") {
        link.text('OVERVIEW').attr('href', 'http://%LIVESCORINGHOST%/%YEAR%/home/%LEAGUEID%?MODULE=MESSAGE12');
        return false; //break out
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.filter()` for this

```
$("#hsubmenuitems a").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == "Home"
}).attr('href', 'http://%LIVESCORINGHOST%/%YEAR%/home/%LEAGUEID%?MODULE=MESSAGE12');
```

This will extract the anchors with text exactly equal  to "Home"